# What is the `0` equivalent oflag in <fcntl.h>?

Tags: c

To open a semaphore, I've seen the following expression:

```
sem_t semaphore = sem_open("/sempath", 0);
```

The man page says that that integer at the end is the "oflag" and that I should read more about the oflags in `fcntl.h` but I can't figure out what oflag the number `0` get's mapped to.

---

What does the `0` mean in the code above? Is it `O_RDWR`?

More generally: What numbers do the flags in `fcntl.h` get mapped to and how can I find them?

Comment: Zero means no flags are set.

Comment: #define O_RDONLY        0x0000

Comment: I strongly recommend against passing `0` as flag and explicitly specifying `O_RDONLY`. This code should be rejected in a code review.

Comment: @jmq Where'd you find that? Would you mind sharing a link?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks! I'd really appreciate a source

Comment: @Cheetah Are you sure they are equivalent? I'd really appreciate a source.

Comment: On my system `O_RDONLY` is set in `/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h`.

Comment: @Cheetah Thanks! Found the file - but can't find O_RDONLY

Comment: That is because it may be different on different platforms. But all information I read about `open`, and its flags, mentions only the named constants. Deviating from those seems foolish to me.

Comment: @Cheetah Yeah - I understand. Do you think is https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/fcntl-linux.h.html the right code?

Comment: @sueszli: You did not say what system you are using. The [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) says the `oflag` argument to `sem_open` may have the `O_CREAT` or `O_EXCL` bits set. So, obviously, if no bits are set, that means neither flag is set. On macOS 10.14.6, the man page says “The value of oflag is formed by or'ing the following values” and also shows `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL`. The identity element (like 0 for addition or 1 for multiplication) of logical OR is 0. So that is the “nothing” of logical OR.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh of course! I'm on the latest Ubuntu. Thank you for your detailed answer - now it makes sense. I'd leave it this way then - apparently 0 is the right code in this case and there is no alternative.

Comment: I would disagree with using `O_RDONLY`, let alone requiring it. Maybe there is documentation saying its value is zero and/or that it can be used with `sem_open`, but I do not see it, so using it with a function for which it is not documented is bad practice. A Linux man page for `open` says “In historical implementations the value of O_RDONLY is zero. Because of that, it is not possible to detect the presence of O_RDONLY and another option. Future implementations should encode O_RDONLY and O_WRONLY as bit flags so that…”, indicating we should not expect `O_RDONLY` to be zero in the future.

Comment: The [POSIX man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) also indicates we should not expect `O_RDONLY` to be zero.

Comment: @Cheatah: The question is about `sem_open`, not `open`. Are you aware of any documentation that indicates `O_RDONLY` may be passed to `sem_open`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, I am not aware of such documentation. It makes little sense to me to use O_RDONLY, but the `sem_open` documentation that I can find does refer to the `open` call.

Comment: In fact, the posix man page you refer to explicitly states for `sem_open` that "If flags other than `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` are specified in the `oflag` parameter, the effect is unspecified."

Comment: @sueszli - I found it in fcntl.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the `0` mean in the code above? Is it `O_RDWR`?

`0` means no flags. The flags argument passed to `sem_open` and similar routines, such as `open` is the logical OR of single bits or bit-fields that are defined by the various symbols documented for these routines. When there are no flags, no bits are ORed into the argument, so its value should be the identity element of the OR operation, which is zero.

> What numbers do the flags in `fcntl.h` get mapped to and how can I find them?

You can find them in `fcntl.h` or the files it includes. Or, more easily, you can write a program that prints them:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#include <fcntl.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("O_CREAT is 0x%" PRIxMAX ".\n", (uintmax_t) O_CREAT);
    printf("O_EXCL is 0x%" PRIxMAX ".\n", (uintmax_t) O_EXCL);
}
```

However, you should not rely on these symbols having particular values, especially across different POSIX implementations.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to write this answer!

Comment: For anyone curious; This is the output of the given program: `O_CREAT is 0x40.
O_EXCL is 0x80.`